# how to set the height of a scrollbar in Tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, scrollbar

I have a table that is linked to the scrollbar. It works but the height of the scrollbar is very short.
how can I set his height?

```py
class table(ttk.Treeview):

    def _init__(self,frame,scroll_width,list_height,side,x_crol,y_crol,lable_place_x,
                               lable_place_y):
        self.side = side
        scroll = Scrollbar(frame, orient="vertical", width=scroll_width)
        scroll.pack(side=side)
        scroll.place(x=x_crol, y=y_crol)
        ttk.Treeview.__init__(self,frame, yscrollcommand=scroll.set, height=list_height)
        self.pack(side=LEFT, padx=lable_place_x + 30, pady=lable_place_y + 50)
        scroll.config(command=self.yview)

    scroll_width=20
    tab_side=LEFT
    x=650
    y= 160
    frame=hospitalFrame
    list_height=20
    c = 80
    
    lable_place_x = 80
    lable_place_y=70
            
    hospital_tabel=table(frame,scroll_width,list_height,tab_side,x,y,lable_place_x,
                         lable_place_y)
    
    hospitalFrame.pack(fill='both',expand=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Please fix the formatting of the code.

Comment: Remove scroll.place(x=x_crol, y=y_crol).  Your code is not clearly.

Comment: Deleting scroll.place(x=x_crol, y=y_crol) will cause the scrollbar to be placed in an unwanted place
 Explanation of the code - its a table class that adds a scrollbar (to the table).
I want to extend the length of the scrollbar

Comment: Your design is a bit strange, have both `side` and `x, y` options for the scrollbar.  Calling both `pack()` and `place()` (the later will override the former) on the scrollbar is another strange thing.  Think again carefully on your design first.

Comment: This is not the solution to the problem

Answer (score 0):

You could put the scrollbar inside an individual frame and specify the frame's height. You can also write `expand = True, fill = BOTH` when you pack the scrollbar inside the frame.